# How to create a script to screenshot pages on a website in python

Tags: python

The export function in my company's website does not work, and we have to manually snip various model diagnostics on a website(hundreds of models). Ideally, we would export everything to pdf. But now, we have to click on hundreds of links and screen shot the information in those links. Is there a way to easily create a script that automatically screen shots certain pages? Is there a way to use a "Record" function as is done in Excel VBA where I can perform a set of steps and have Python automatically create a code template? We are looking for a solution that is simple/elegant.

Comment: look into requests and BeautifulSoup, maybe selenium

Comment: Probably because this isn't really an SO question. It's meant more for specific errors etc. Not general advise.

Comment: Requests for libraries are off-topic; your Question would get better attention with a structure around "what exactly have you tried so far?" We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should write some code that you tried. Maybe it is because of this.

Comment: You can do it by selenium. look at this: https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-screenshot/

Comment: @zorny understandable, but you're better served by just googling and seeing what you find

Comment: @zorny would you get in trouble if you were trying to solve a problem and clicked on a link they had blocked? Seems counterproductive if that's the case

Comment: @zorny consider what steps would be needed to create the script you want? then write those down and start making your program

Comment: Never knew you could use a keyboard Screen shot macro emulator. It's not my webpage, it's my company's webpage. I Just chose python as thats what is used at my company.

Answer (score 1):

I would say selenium is your friend here. This is a library used for browser automation, so:

- Set up a Selenium Chrome driver
- Open up each and every web page (made easier if there was just a main portion of the url and you could change the page-id per iteration for example)
- Screenshot the Selenium Driver in each iteration and save to a folder.

Comment: this is a comment